# SonarQube branch plugin: no coverage in long living branch

Tags: git, sonarqube

I'm using the free sonar plugin: https://github.com/msanez/sonar-branch-community

I'm using Sonar 7.0. I can get the coverage in my master branch. Not in the short-living-branches (which is expected. It's only available since sonar 7.4 and probably the free plugin needs an update for it).
But I can also not get the coverage in my long-living branches while they contains the same configuration as the master branch (which shows coverage). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: upgrade to latest sonar

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to a newer version of SonarQube and use the [SonarQube Community Branch Plugin](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin). This plugin aims to support the same metric gathering and reporting across short and long lived branches as SonarQube developer edition, but without the limitations on cost or lines of code.

Full Disclosure: I am the author of this plugin